# Why does AWS Route53 not keep consistent DNS zones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

In a setup with EC2 instances, and a properly configured zone file, I've found that AWS periodically changes their DNS servers. This means one has to go all the way back to the initial ISP setup and update those DNS records every time they change.

This ISP (and most every ISP) actually allows you to set up private DNS nameservers, but this only works if the DNS servers (addresses) are consistent.  Otherwise the site will become completely unreachable when AWS randomly changes their zone files/DNS servers. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Does your registrar allow you to use fully qualified domain names when specifying the DNS servers to use?

Comment: Yes, but you have to do a round-robin setup which doesn't work so well when the DNS servers randomly change hostnames/IPs, etc.

Comment: The DNS servers should not change hostnames.  They infrequently change the IP addresses (with prior client notification), so if you can use FQDN, you should.

Comment: Unfortunately all four AWS/Route53 DNS hostnames randomly changed recently, making the entire attached EC2-based network unavailable.

Comment: They are not supposed to do that, someone probably didn't want to get yelled at and hoped for the best! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP addresses of Route 53's name servers assigned to your hosted zones should not change.  I would post to the [Route 53](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=87) forums explaining what you are seeing.